# Pass a variable value from javascript value to php variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass a text string to a php file,

Here is my code:

```
var t2 = new Text(figure_defaultFigureTextStr, x, y + figure_defaultFigureRadiusSize/2,  
figure_defaultFigureTextFont, figure_defaultFigureTextSize);

t2.style.fillStyle = figure_defaultFillTextStyle;

f.addPrimitive(t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically PHP is a server side language, you cannot execute it client-side.

So the best bid would be, to send a HttpPost request alongwith the variable value. This would send the data to the server. There you can save the data of it inside a file or what so ever.